# Is it compulsory to write int main(int argc, char *argv[]), can't use some other names instead of argc and *argv[]?

Tags: c, visual-c++, command-line-arguments

I am having some real trouble around here giving command line arguments to Visual Studio in the project options itself (in 'Configuration Properties' -> 'Debugging').

I wrote this "`int main(int argc)`" after the "`int main(int main_i)`" did not work. In the MS visual studio property pages' Command line argument for the project I am not sure what I should write. I only want to pass a single integer to designate whether a file is to read or written to thus a mere int argc. I do not need the char `*argv[]`. I have tried a few values in the command line argument text box but it is not reaching the exe file when it executes, it shows what I did not enter at all.

Could you just provide me with a single simple example of what I need to enter in the MSVS C++ Property Pages' Command Line Argument space? I simply can't find any example on how to give the command line arguments to MSVS.

I also do not understand WHY I need to rebuild the whole project even when I just modified the command line argument value only??

Comment: Ints passed to your prog don't go into argc. Read that tutorial again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want your program to understand a single integer command line argument, you still have to use `argc` and `argv`. Something like this ought to do it:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Need a command line argument.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int arg = atoi(argv[1]);
    // now you have an integer
    // do whatever with it...
}
```

The C standard requires that the `main` function have specific sets of parameters. One of the allowed combinations is `(int, char *[])`. You can *name* the parameters whatever you want, but they're almost always called `argc` and `argv`.

Answer (score 6):

The *names* are just a well-established convention, you can use any names you want (though it might raise  some eyebrows), however, I have only seen code that has used *both* arguments in the specified order.

In the pre-ANSI days it was possible to  simply have `int main()`, and it still is .. but these days `argc` `argv` are usually supplied.

You can't just supply one of the parameters.

Comment: In the post-ANSI days it is still possible to have `int main()` (which you seem to have hinted at).

Comment: @SethCarnegie Do you think I need to be more explicit about that? I guess I'm promoting "good practices" by encouraging the use of `argc`, `argv` ..

Comment: I don't think using `argc` and `argv` is necessarily a good practice. Sometimes you need it and sometimes you don't. I just mentioned what I mentioned because if you say it _was_ possible, it implies that it's not anymore, which it is (they even use it in examples in the Standard).

Comment: @SethCarnegie I'll reword it then .. thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 5):

Variables names are only for the compiler. They will be converted to addresses in the binary image. You can pass upto 3 parameters for main.

Here is what I tried -

```
int main(int i, char* a[], char* e[])
```

As you can see the names are not the normal names.
The first parameter is the number of command line arguments, the second is the actual array of arguments and the third is an array of environment variables.

In fact, main can take any number of arguments, but the rest, after the third will be invalid. This would still compile -

```
int main(int i, char* a[], char* e[], char* j[])
```

And just for fun, you can even do this -

```
int main(int i, float a, float b, float c, float d, float e)
```

Comment: Actually all other `main`s except `int main()` and `int main(int, char*[])` are not guaranteed to work.

Comment: @SethCarnegie yes (says the Standard)! But unless you build on a DS9k, it will.

Comment: @H2CO3 I just like looking things up in the standard.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: That's true. The standard also says the following - [Note: it is recommended that any further (optional) parameters be added after argv. ]. I believe all compilers support at least 3.

Answer (score 4):

Even a simple `main` is allowed, and still you can access those arguments.

```
int main()
{
    int nArgCount = __argc;
    char** pArgs= __argv;

    printf("Argument Count: %d\n", nArgCount-1);
    printf("Arguments:");

    for(int nIndex = 1; nIndex<nArgCount; ++nIndex)
        printf("%s, ", pArgs[nIndex]);
}
```

You can also use `GetCommandLine` function to access the command line. The important aspect of not having/using the `main`'s argument is you can still **access command line arguments in any function**.

Answer (score 1):

Like others mentioned, it is just a matter of convenience and that Kernighan and Ritchie used those arguments in the first C version it has been carried along that way.

You are allowed to freely use anything.

Here's a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int arglen, char *args[])
{
        std::cout << "Running: " << *args << std::endl;
    while (--arglen > 0)
        std::cout << *++args << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I use Visual C++ 2010 Express.  If you do, you can press Alt+F7 to bring the project properties, go to Configuration Properties > Debugging and type your command line arguments in `Command Arguments`.

That's it.

Comment: The OP seems to have misunderstood what `arglen` and `args` are for

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `char *argv[]`, if you want to read the values of command line arguments. Else you can drop it.

If you just want to have a single integer to differentiate between two things, then you have one method to do this. Just pass command line argument for one thing and don't pass any for other. Now you don't need `char *argv[]`. Now you pass command line argument for only one thing then the value of `argc` is `2`, i.e., executable's name + command line argument.

And if you don't pass command line argument, then its value is only `1`, i.e. executable's name.

Comment: Your explanation is not clear. Your thought is better desribed by [@Ajay](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11490369)